# How can i resolve the start limit hit error

Tags: python

Hi I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4

I am trying to program a discord bot for my server

Here is the error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/discordbot.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status discordbot.service
● discordbot.service - My Discord Bot Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/discordbot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2020-06-03 22:28:41 +08; 20min ago
 Main PID: 856 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped My Discord Bot Service.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start My Discord Bot Service.
```

Here is the log to see my error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -e -u discordbot
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My Discord Bot Service.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Succeeded.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Service RestartSec=1
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Scheduled restart jo
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped My Discord Bot Service.
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Start request repeat
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Failed with result '
Jun 03 22:28:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start My Discord Bot Service.

[2]+  Stopped                 journalctl -e -u discordbot
```

Here is the code for the systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=My Discord Bot Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
Restart=always
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/discordbot/discordbot.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried to find solutions for hours but none helped

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is your `discordbot.py` doing? Have you tried to start it manually using the `ExecStart` command? It seems it exits immediately after it has been started and hence the systemd refuses to restart it because it failed to quickly.

Comment: @a_guest My mistake, there was an error with my discordbot.py file, I fixed it but it still gives me the same error (start limit hit)...also the function of my discord bot is to clear messages using the clear command, join the voice channel to play music using the join and play command and disconnect from it when the user uses the leave command

Comment: Please update your question with the new error (if it changed). It would also be helpful too see the output of running the Python script directly, i.e. not through systemd. Does it work that way? I suppose there's an error in your script, but without seeing the code it's hard to tell.